# Varbinary encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, varbinary

I got a `varbinary` field in my database, and got some problems with displaying special (Polish) characters like `ąśćężźć`.

Example: `SELECT local_name from items WHERE id = 140` returns: `Pieczęć`, the problem appears when I want to print this data on my website (encoding  `UTF-8` there), then the `Pieczęć` turns into the following string: `Piecz��` tried also to use `utf8_encode()` PHP function but it gives the following result: `Pieczêæ`.

How can I solve that so it will print the special characters without problem?

Comment: Why not just use a `VARCHAR` with UTF-8 charset? I'm not sure it will solve the problem, it's just a general comment...

Comment: why are you storing non binary data in a binary field type ?

Comment: Its better to read the binary data on the game server.

Comment: Do you also need to specify the character set in the meta tag or headers?

Comment: @Josh Yes, because without that my page won't support those special characters also.

Answer (score 0):

same adivce as here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254131/1489924

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
```

and/or

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

worked for me in most situations.
Good luck!